# How to detect if the current post is the last post in the category

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a website with my photos, divided to categories.

In my site, each photo is a post and they are displayed when a viewer enters a specific category.

I have next and previous buttons to move between posts, and I want to disable the "next" button when a viewer is in the last post.

What I need is to find a way to detect whether the current post is the last post in the category.

[link](http://www.eyalbinehaker.com/) to my website

Script for next and previous buttons:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(true, '', false)); ?>"><div class="next"><p>NEXT</p></div></a>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(true, '', true)); ?>"><div class="prev"><p>PREV</p></div></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

get_adjacent_post will return an empty string if no post exists.

Check to see if there is a post with something like this

```
$nextpost = get_adjacent_post(true, '', true);
if ($nextpost != "") {
    ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextpost); ?>"><div class="prev"><p>PREV</p></div></a><?php
}
```

Comment: You were pretty close... the correct condition was this:

 $nextpost = get_adjacent_post(true, '', false);
   if ($nextpost == "") {
     ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextpost); ?>"><div class="prev"><p>PREV</p></div></a><?php
  }

But your elegant was correct though

Comment: I was doing it for previous post, that's why I passed in true as the third argument. And if the function returns an empty string is the post does not exist, why are you checking for it to be equal to "" ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct conditioning is:

```
 $nextpost = get_adjacent_post(true, '', false); if ($nextpost == "") { ?><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextpost); ?>"><div class="prev"><p>PREV</p></div></a><?php }
```

This solution was only possible thanks to the very elegnt direction suggested by the user  "bsoist" which replied to this question.